# What is the antonym for client-server?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

For example - there are client-server applications. The application of this type runs on one machine (client) and conntects to another machine (server) in order to work. What can I call an application that to work only needs one machine?

Comment: Locally installed.

Comment: ‘Antonym’ is a dangerously fickle word. I would say the antonym of a ‘client-server’ application would be a _server-client_ application: one that’s installed on the server, but needs to connect to a client machine to work (similar to how most web apps or browser-based apps work).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or a *peer–peer program*, or a *non-networked program*, amongst others. Pick your favorite axis.

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet, _antonym_ means the semantic opposite of a word. In case the word is not an (obvious) member of a dialectical pair like _left, right_, such a semantic _opposite_ may be a tricky thing to ask for: What would be the "antonym" for "black-currant tea"? Strawberry coffee? There are tens, if not hundreds of common application architectures, of which client-server is just one. Assuming that there is an exact opposite architecture is very much like assuming a specific tea flavour has an opposite.

Comment: @oerkelens Strawberry coffee sounds absolutely godawful.

Answer (score 8):

That would be a "standalone" application.

> Word processing works in a standalone manner, while email requires a client-server organization.

Answer (score 1):

You can either call it a **Standalone Application** or a **Thick Client Application**.

An application that does not require *any* network connectivity, is usually called a **Standalone Application**. While an application, that does not require a connection to a server system in order to *run*, is called a **Thick Client** (NOTE: these applications can use a connection to a server for some of the features, but unlike a *Thin Client*, these do not entirely depend on the server).  These terms are loosely in the tech industry.

Examples:

- Thick clients: MS word, Video games, Acrobat Reader, Web browser,
  etc.
- Thin clients: Websites, Mobile applications, Email clients, etc.